# BigQuery SQL: Create Daily Current Status Table from Log Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a log table with a record of any change in status.
For example:

```
Updated_at  Customer    Status
01/01/2020     A       Trial
01/01/2020     C       Trial
05/01/2020     B       Trial
06/03/2020     C       Free
15/03/2020     B       Full
05/04/2020     A       Free
07/05/2020     C       Full
10/09/2020     A       Full
10/09/2020     C       Remove
```

** Updated_at is timestamp

I need to make Daily Status Table where I can see the current status of customers by day:

```
Date         Customer   Status
01/01/2020      A   Trial
01/01/2020      C   Trial
02/01/2020      A   Trial
02/01/2020      C   Trial
|       
|       
05/01/2020      A   Trial
05/01/2020      B   Trial
05/01/2020      C   Trial
|
|       
06/03/2020      A   Trial
06/03/2020      B   Trial
06/03/2020      C   Free
|       
|       
15/03/2020      A   Trial
15/03/2020      B   Full
15/03/2020      C   Free
|       
|   
10/09/2020     A    Full
10/09/2020     B    Full
10/09/2020     C    Remove
```

That is, if there is no change in status for that day then the status is recorded from the last change date in the log table.

My try:

First I create a column with a sequence of dates

Next, I need To Join a log table with dates

```
WITH CTE_DATES AS
(
SELECT
  *
FROM
  UNNEST( GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY( CURRENT_DATE(), DATE('2019-05-30'), INTERVAL -1 DAY) )  as Date
)
SELECT  d.date,
lt.Customer,
lt.Status,
extract (date from updated_at) as LT_Date
FROM `logTable` lt join CTE_DATES d on  extract (date from updated_at)<=d.Date
```

But by this method, I get status not only by the last log date

```
Date       Customer     Status  Updated_at
12/09/2020      A       Trial   01/01/2020
12/09/2020      A       Free    05/04/2020
12/09/2020      A       Full    10/09/2020
```

What's the correct way to Join tables to get the last record in each sequence of dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend approaching this by creating the dates *per row*.  This makes it simple to put the data in the row you want.  It is also much more efficient than generating all dates at once and then using joins and other mechanisms to generate the data:

```
with lt as (
      select lt.*,
             lead(updated_at, 1, current_date) over (partition by customer order by updated_at) as next_updated_at
      from `logTable` lt
     )
select dte, lt.customer, lt.status
from lt cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(lt.updated_at,
                                date_add(lt.next_updated_at, interval -1 day),
                                interval 1 day)
                               ) dte;
```

Comment: Probably `date_add(lt.next_updated_at, interval -1 day)` was meant...

Comment: Hi,
by this method, I get last day like yesterday  and not today